# Android Tv unit's keycode's for right and left are not changing when app language and layout is changed from LTR to RTL

Tags: android, localization, android-tv

Basically, I have developed an android ATV application that has localization. It supports English and Arabic languages. On changing the language I have handled the language changes and LTR -> RTL switching. But the issue I am facing is the keypad functionalities which I have set for LEFT and RIGHT are not automatically updated i.e still key left is functioning as what it was in the LTR layout and RTL as what it was in the LTR layout. Is there any way it can change automatically i.e left should have the functionality of right in RTL and right as left in RTL layout.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "key left is functioning as what it was in the LTR layout"?

Comment: Even with layout in different direction users will still expect their left/right key presses to navigate focus in direction they're pressing. If you're writing a custom keypress event handler that's what you should update.

Comment: @CommonsWare for Normal English users layout is from LTR and I have defined different functionalities for the left key and right key. So when I change the language and layout gets changed to RTL, key functionality is not changed. should I interchange the funtionalities again for left and right based on langugage or will it automatically changed by Android system

Comment: "I have defined different functionalities for the left key and right key" -- could you provide a [mcve] of what you mean by this?